# Programatically opening a link in target="_blank" does not work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, csv, safari

See example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/dRjuBCR7buHYkIPAYDkX?p=preview

It works in Firefox, Chrome, and (I believe) IE, but not Safari. If I remove the target line, it works in all of the above, so the `target` is the problem from what I can tell...

```
var a = document.createElement( 'a' );
a.target = '_blank';

a.href = 'http://www.google.ca/'
document.body.appendChild( a );
a.click();
```

(This is a simplified example; I'm using a download like this to serve a generated CSV file to the user)

Is there any way around this? I don't want the clobber the user's view with CSV.

**Edit:** Alternate question: I have the URL to a CSV file. How do I make Safari download it?

Comment: Automatic popups are blocked in most browsers.

Comment: Yes, but most say "Oh hey, we're trying to open something, please let us." Safari just fails silently.